# jquery how to access events on html that was inserted to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

In my web app I have an unordered list of 15 items that appear on load. I am grabbing 100 new items from an API using ajax and adding them to the current `ul` by using `.append(html)`. Each `li` has a checkbox next to it that when selected needs to call `some_function`.

The elements that have been rendered are able to access `some_function` but not the newly loaded ones. How can I access `some_function` on the newly loaded ajax items? I've never dealt with this before and apparently since the items aren't "rendered" yet they can't access functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code I am guessing that you have bound an event handler directly to the checkboxes

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(event) {
    // Your code
});
```

To make this work with content added after the handler was created you would need to use a delegated handler that binds to a lower level, unchanged element and bubbles an event up to the checkboxes. I have used `document` though it would be advisable to bind it to a dom node further up, most likely the `ul` that the checkboxes are added to.

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(event) {
    // Your code
});
```

Comment: Thank you and thanks to all for the hints. I really never knew anything about event delegation until now. So the next question is that since jQuery will favor `.on` going forward, is it safe and best practice to always assign events by `.on`?

Comment: `.on` certainly gives you the flexibility to add elements to the DOM at a later time and still maintain the handler. You'll also notice that as it bubbles up the DOM it can also be used to trigger an event on a different element should you need it to. Read up on it, I'd recommend using it :)

Comment: I did and I will some more too so thanks. I changed it out in my code and all is good!

Answer (score 1):

This is a great situation where you can use the jQuery `on()` function

You can read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation -

```
$(document).on('change',".YourInputClass", some_function);
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

You should use event delegation for such scenarios.. Basically you bind the handler to the parent element and filter out by a selector to trigger the handler.

Below is the pseudo code,

```
$('ul').on('click', '.checkbox', function () {
   some_function.call(this); //maintain the context if it is an external function.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `delegate the events.`

If  `<div id="div1"></div>` is a dynamically injected element and you want to attach the click event

```
$('staticContainer').on('click', '#div1', some_function);
```